# Calculate irradiation from a LED lamp

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, estimation, light-emitting-diodes

I am working with cell culture and I want to irradiate a 96-well plate with a single color led lamp (let's say the peak is at 450nm). It's just a test, so a rough estimation would do. 
I've been trying to figure out how to obtain the irradiance ($\text {W/cm}^2$)and the irradiation dose ($\text {J/cm}^2$) in function of time. I only have the specifications from the lamp: Luminous efficiency 85 Lm/W; Luminosity 4250 Lm; Angle aperture 120º. According to the setup, the cells are placed below the light source at 10cm distance.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you want to find out? Energy delivered to the culture as a function of time?

Comment: Exactly. I need to know more about the energy delivered into the cell culture.

Comment: Looking at units it seems like (luminosity)/(luminous efficiency) has the dimensions of power. And power*time is energy

Comment: Problem is that the W in the technical information refers to the LED electrical consumption and not to the irradiated energy.